# How do I copy a file in netrw?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, netrw, filesystem

The current working directory is `./A/B/`. An empty document is opened when I type `vim`, and the netrw is opened with command `:e.` The window is split by `vs.`, and I can navigate to the upper level directory, i.e., `./A/`. Now I'd like to copy a file `a_file.jpg` from `./A/B/` to `./A/`.

I tried `yy` on the target file and `p` in the target window (directory), but it did not achieve my goal.

Is there any way that can achieve the goal without installing extra plugins?

Comment: Try the following: hit `mt` on the target directory in which you want to make a copy of a file (to mark it ; the path to the folder should appear in the banner after `Copy/Move Tgt:`), hit `mf` on the file you want to copy to mark it as well, then hit `mc` to actually perform the copy.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You cannot use `y`, `p` etc., to copy files in netrw - it comes with its own commands. See [`:h netrw-mc`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pi_netrw.txt.html#netrw-mc):

```
MARKED FILES: COPYING                                           netrw-mc {{{2
            (See netrw-mf and netrw-mr for how to mark files)
                      (Uses the global marked file list)

Select a target directory with mt (netrw-mt).  Then change directory,
select file(s) (see netrw-mf), and press "mc".  The copy is done
from the current window (where one does the mf) to the target.

If one does not have a target directory set with netrw-mt, then netrw
will query you for a directory to copy to.

One may also copy directories and their contents (local only) to a target
directory.
```

Your case is simplified since `./A` is the parent of `./A/B`:

1. Open `./A/B`, move to the line having `../`,
2. Mark it with `mt`
3. Move to the line with the file you want to copy.
4. Press `mf`, and then `mc`.

Example:

```
$ tree foo
foo
└── bar
    └── test

1 directory, 1 file
$ vim foo/bar
```

Now:

1. Move to `..` and press `mt`:

   [image]
2. The header will change to show the current target:

   [image]
3. Move to the file (here `test`) and press `mf`. It gets highlighted for me:

   [image]
4. Press `mc` - the highlighting goes away. Now navigate to the parent folder - the file should be present:

   [image]

Answer (score 11):

I would do this from the command line mode:

- Select the file you need in netrw
- Open command the line and type - `:!mv <C-R><C-F> ../<C-R><C-F>`

Here `<C-R><C-F>` inserts file name under cursor, so you don't have to type the file name.

Comment: Very cool.  Doesn't include the full path if you've traversed into your tree in netrw...

Answer (score 5):

- Set cursor on
  `./` (or directory in which you want to copy)
  , press `mt`
- Set cursor on file you want copy, press `mf`, then `mc`, type a name of new file, `enter`

Comment: I got `(netrw) tried using g:netrw_localcopycmd<cp>; it doesn't work!$ `

Comment: solution for osx https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31811335/copying-files-with-vims-netrw-on-mac-os-x-is-broken

Comment: @HarryMoreno it worked on my osx iTerm2

Comment: I got the same error as @HarryMoreno. The answer from Boris Serebrov worked for me instead.